# Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, numberformatexception

So my main plan is to have a GUI with a button and two `jTextFields`. When the button is pressed it starts a new thread of the `Runnah` class I have made. The `Runnah` class is suppose to get the input from the text fields;

The `Runnah` class then gets a `NumberFormatException` when I run `gui.getSeconds();`

**The MainGUI Class**

```
public class MainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Runnah runnah;
Thread thread;

public MainGUI() {
    initComponents();
    //runnah = new Runnah();
}                        

private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        runnah = new Runnah();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    thread = new Thread(runnah);
    thread.start();
}                                           

public String getInput(){
    String temp = textInp.getText();
    return temp;
}
public int getSeconds(){
    return Integer.parseInt(secInp.getText());
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                new MainGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField secInp;
private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField textInp;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**The Runnah Class**

```
public class Runnah implements Runnable{

private MainGUI gui;

private Robot robot;

public Runnah() throws AWTException{
    this.robot = new Robot();
    gui = new MainGUI();
}

public Runnah(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    String temp = gui.getInput();
    CharSequence input = temp;
    int seconds = 1;
    seconds = gui.getSeconds() * 1000;

    robot.delay(seconds);
}
```

If any more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: This field `private MainGUI gui;` remains `null`. You haven't initialized it.

Comment: You are accessing a Swing component from a `Thread` that isn't the EDT. This is in violation of the Swing threading model. Violation of the the threading model can cause race hazards, unexpected bugs, and (in rare cases) death.

Comment: Thank you Sotirios, I fixed that. It's not reading the input from my textField for the seconds though. Now saying it's a String of ""

Comment: In such cases I recommend to use the final-keyword so the compiler can tell you your initialization problem.

Comment: Now you seem to be creating a new instance of the `MainGUI` rather than passing in the extant one.

Comment: Yep, as per @BoristheSpider, your other class must have a reference to the actual visualized GUI instance, not to another new instance that you make and that is not displayed and that is completely unrelated to the one that is displayed.

Comment: How do I reference the existing visualized GUI?

Comment: How do you gain a reference to any object? Same answer here: Pass it into the class, either via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

Answer (score 0):

I just wasn't referencing the existing MainGUI class.